# How to databind multiple column names in checkboxlist in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a checkbox list in my page and try to databind it. Here is what i do:

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Select subj,numb,section from Courses where term=@term",CommonFunctions.con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term",CommonFunctions.currentTerm);
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
checkboxlist_courses.DataSource = dt;
checkboxlist_courses.DataTextField = "subj";
checkboxlist_courses.DataBind();
```

This works fine. The problem is, i can only show the column "subj" in the checkbox list. What i want to do is, i want to show "subj" + "numb" + "section" in the checkbox list. So, what can i do about this?

I tried

```
checkboxlist_courses.DataTextField = "subj" + "numb" + "section";
```

but it did not work.

I also tried

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Select subj,numb,section as fullname from Courses where term=@term",CommonFunctions.con);
checkboxlist_courses.DataTextField = "fullname";
```

But this time only "section" column is displayed.
Thanks

Comment: Well yeah, is there a field name called `sujnumsection`? Because all you are doing is combining the string, _then_ assigning it to the property.

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, the compiler exactly says the same thing :)) does not work this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine fields in SQL query instead:

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("Select subj + ' ' + numb + ' ' + section as [combined] from Courses where term=@term",CommonFunctions.con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term",CommonFunctions.currentTerm);
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
checkboxlist_courses.DataSource = dt;
checkboxlist_courses.DataTextField = "combined";
checkboxlist_courses.DataBind();
```

Comment: i was thinking about replying my own question because that is exactly what i did just now. But i will accept your answer. Thanks!